# Synonym request - megaman-x-street-fighter

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Can megaman-x-street-fighter be made a synonym of street-fighter-x-megaman please?

megaman-x-street-fighter was the early working title of the game street-fighter-x-megaman, we've had 2 questions raised so far, both of them using megaman-x-street-fighter and subsequently retagged.

The game is released as street-fighter-x-megaman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tada~](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/street-fighter-x-megaman/synonyms)

All done.

For future reference, linking the tags, especially via tag syntax, makes these kinds of requests a whole lot easier. Then I can just "click-done".